# How to get the pivot point at center

Tags: mesh

I have 2 mesh and i have join them with ctrl+j and made a single mesh. And i want the pivot point to be center of the new mesh i have made from joining the 2. I have tried geometry to origin but also it did not fix the center. Its on the top of the match stick and not in the center of my mesh. I can go in the edit mode and move my model and set the pivot manually. But without doing manually how can to fix it to the center.[image]

[image]

Final image (answer for the question)
[image]

Comment: Select the whole mesh in *Edit Mode* (**A**) and press **Shift+S-->Cursor to Selected**. Then go to *Object Mode* and press **Shift+Ctrl+Alt+C-->Origin to 3D Cursor**

Comment: You did not get what i mean. The top mesh its pivot is at the center and the bottom stick pivot is at its center. I have join both the mesh ctrl+J and as said above select all and cursor to selected and then in object mode origin to 3d cursor. After doing that step i pivot point should be at the center of the mesh that is some where near to the red axis not at the top. As you can see my new image

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how it's done for versions > v2.90 :

Choose either one of the bottom two:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Select you object. Then, simply Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and when the menu pops up just press <kbd>O</kbd>. This resets the origin to the center of the selected object.

Comment: You did not get what i mean. The top mesh its pivot is at the center and the bottom stick pivot is at its center. I have join both the mesh ctrl+J and as said above select all and cursor to selected and then in object mode origin to 3d cursor. After doing that step i pivot point should be at the center of the mesh that is some where near to the red axis not at the top. As you can see my new image

Comment: @atek You did not follow my directions. You moved the 3d cursor to the center in object mode then pressed ctrl alt shift c, origin to 3d cursor. That is an extra long and not always foolproof method to fix this. I do not require you to move the 3d cursor. Instead of pressing origin to 3d cursor, press origin to geometry, or "O". Do this in object mode and make sure the object is selected.

Answer (score 3):

Position your 3D cursor either by <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> selection (with parts of your mesh selected in Edit Mode), or moving the 3D cursor via the Properties panel. After that choose Origin to 3D cursor...

[image]

[image]

Comment: You did not get what i mean. The top mesh its pivot is at the center and the bottom stick pivot is at its center. I have join both the mesh ctrl+J and as said above select all and cursor to selected and then in object mode origin to 3d cursor. After doing that step i pivot point should be at the center of the mesh that is some where near to the red axis not at the top. As you can see my new image

Comment: You can move the origin anywhere you can move the 3D cursor. Anywhere.

Comment: manually i can move but i want to fix the center without manually

Answer (score 1):

I think i got my solution hope it helps for others. Select you object in object mode. Then, simply Press CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+C and when the menu pops up just press O as every body suggested but the center point never come in the center. After following all above step. After u press CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+C popup and we select origin to geometry still to it do not come at center. Go to left hand panel as show in .gif image . Set origin (or u can press f6 operator popup) there is type (origin to geometry) and below it is **center in** that there are 2 option (median center and bound center) if u click on the median center as default is on the top only and if we select and change to **bound center** it come exactly to the center of all the geometry. That's what i need i got. Thanks to everybody who have taking the efforts.