# Align a single object along Y axis

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I have ***one*** mesh, a tapered cylinder, that I wish to realign so that it is in the direct center of the world with it's length and middle on the Y axis. It is a duplicate of an object that was previously rotated, but for this iteration I need it dead center for future mirroring. Thank you.

I'm fairly new so please keep it simple :s

Comment: read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/65679/1853 and: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14294/how-to-recenter-an-objects-origin or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33553/change-pivot-point-for-selected-edges/33557#33557

Comment: It's difficult to figure your problem without screenshot. You can use [ALT] + [G] to reset the cylinder position and [ALT] + [R] to reset it's rotation. Does this help you ?

Answer (score 1):

Go to edit mode on the object. Select which face you want to align with the world origin. Shift+s, 2 to set curser to center of face. exit edit mode to object mode. set curser to world origin. snap object to curser. then rotate object along which ever axis you need. see pictures.[image]